# Filter nested JSON with jQuery for empty values

Tags: javascript

I have a nested `JSON` which looks like this:

```
var unfilteredJSON = {  
   "payload":{  
      "oldKeys":[  
         "125262"
      ],
      "keyData":[  
         {  
            "key":"123456",
            "products":[  
               {  
                  "prodId":"H1",
                  "qty":"1"
               },
               {  
                  "prodId":"H2",
                  "qty":""
               }
            ],
            "rushFee":"true"
         },
         {  
            "key":"234234",
            "products":[  
               {  
                  "prodId":"H1",
                  "qty":"1"
               },
               {  
                  "prodId":"H2",
                  "qty":""
               }
            ],
            "rushFee":"false"
         }
      ],
      "submit":"false"
   }
}
```

The qty key can have empty values in the object. I want to filter the data with `jQuery` method and remove the `object` with blank qty so the `JSON` can look like this -

```
{  
   "payload":{  
      "oldKeys":[  
         "125262"
      ],
      "keyData":[  
         {  
            "key":"123456",
            "products":[  
               {  
                  "prodId":"H1",
                  "qty":"1"
               },
            ],
            "rushFee":"true"
         },
         {  
            "key":"234234",
            "products":[  
               {  
                  "prodId":"H1",
                  "qty":"1"
               },
            ],
            "rushFee":"false"
         }
      ],
      "submit":"false"
   }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `filter` approach which mutates the object in-place:

```js
var unfilteredJSON = {"payload":{"oldKeys":["125262"],"keyData":[{"key":"123456","products":[{"prodId":"H1","qty":"1"},{"prodId":"H2","qty":""}],"rushFee":"true"},{"key":"234234","products":[{"prodId":"H1","qty":"1"},{"prodId":"H2","qty":""}],"rushFee":"false"}],"submit":"false"}};

unfilteredJSON.payload.keyData.forEach(e => 
  e.products = e.products.filter(p => p.qty)
);

console.log(unfilteredJSON);
```

Comment: Note that this does not use jQuery nor should it.

Comment: Its giving me error in Internet explorer  for this - `unfilteredJSON.payload.keyData.forEach(e => 
  e.products = e.products.filter(p => p.qty)
);`

Comment: It's probably the arrow functions. You can replace `=>`s with `function (e) { ... }`.